# Construct std::string from up to X characters, stopping at null char

Tags: c++, stdstring, c++03

I am reading strings from a structure in a file where each string has a fixed length, with `'\0'` padding. They are not zero-terminated if the stored string needs the whole length.

I'm currently constructing `std::string`s out of those like this:

```
// char MyString[1000];
std::string stdmystring(MyString, ARRAYSIZE(MyString));
```

However, this copies the padding, too. I could trim the string now, but is there an elegant and quick way to prevent the copying in the first place?

Speed is more important than space, because this runs in a loop.

Comment: You might use the POSIX strnlen to determine the size. (You should do something like that, otherwise the string::size() is always array size)

Comment: True, definitely an optimization. I will use this if no one comes up how to do this without a second loop for determining the size (which was what I thought about...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solutions are:

1. Just calculate the correct length first

   - either use `strnlen` as Dieter suggested
   - or `std::find(MyString,MyString+ARRAYSIZE(MyString),'\0')` which IME isn't any slower

   note that if your string fits in cache, that will likely dominate the extra loop cost
2. reserve the max string size (you did say space was less important), and write a loop appending characters until you exhaust the width or hit a nul (like `copy_until`)
3. actually create a max-size string initialized with nuls, `strncpy` into it, and optionally erase `unused` nuls if you want the size to be correct

The second option uses only a single loop, while the third notionally uses two (it in the string ctor, and then in the copy). However, the `push_back` of each character seems more expensive than the simple character assignment, so I wouldn't be surprised if #3 were faster in reality. Profile and see!

Comment: At least in Visual Studio, the string construction from a known size uses memcpy and is way faster than anything else, so I'll go with Dieter's method.

Answer (score 2):

Well If size is not a problem one potential way to do it is to create an empty `std::string` then use `reserve()` to pre-allocate the space potentially needed and then add each char until you come across `'\0'`.

```
std::string stdmystring;
stdmystring.reserve(MyString_MAX_SIZE) ;
for(size_t i=0;i<MyString_MAX_SIZE && MyString[i]!='\0';++i);
stdmystring+=MyString[i];
```

`reserve()` garanties you one memory allocation since you know the max_size and the string will never get larger than that.

The calls to += operator function will probably be inlined but it still has to check that the string has the needed capacity which is wasteful in your case. Infact this could be the same or worse than simply using strlen to find the exact length of the string first so you have to test it.

Comment: I'll have to look into some `std::string` implementations later, but I think it is possible that `reserve` is a pessimisation here: It might prevent the Small String Optimization, which might be important for the OP's case, depending on the average and string length.

Comment: Yes this is true but it depends on the situation. The short string has to fit on the space used for size, capacity and pointer for the long string together with its respective size and some flag bit/bits to tell between short and long string. Usually the short string capacity is just a little shorter than 3 machine words.
If the average string size can fit into that reserve() will  indeed be bad for performance but if there are a lot of long enough strings not reserving first can be even worse because of the multiple allocations and copying.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most straightforward way is to overallocate your internal `MyString` array by one byte, always null terminate that final byte, and use the C-string constructor of `std::string`. (Keep in mind that most likely your process will be I/O bound on the file so whatever algorithm the C-string constructor uses should be fine).